# How can I change size of textfield?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a textfield that fill window

```
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rect);

hText = CreateWindowEx(0, "STATIC", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_CENTER, 0, 0, rect.right - rect.left - 20,
                           rect.bottom - rect.top - 40, hwnd, (HMENU) ID_TEXT, hInstance, NULL);
```

and want it to resize when I resize the window. Now, here is my questions:

1. Which function can I change size of hText?
2. Should I put this function to WM_SIZING or WM_SIZE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos) or `MoveWindow`. Call it in `WM_SIZE` or `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`.

```
int x = 33, y = 42, w = 1337, h = 666;
SetWindowPos(hWndOfControl, 0, x, y, w, h, SWP_NOZORDER|SWP_NOACTIVATE);
```